# Как сделать версию сайта для другой страны?

Tags: seo, домен

Спрашивал на тостере, но ответа не получил, теперь обращаюсь за помощью сюда.

Итак: есть интернет-магазин в Украине, поисковиками воспринимается как украинский и имеет неплохие позиции в украинской выдаче. Появилось желание работать и на Россию.

Как сообщить поисковикам о расширении границ? Надо ли создавать RU домен? Просто регистрировать российский домен и копировать на него сайт не есть хорошо.
Я в SEO не силен, помогите пожалуйста с правильным решением.

Answer (score 1):

> Просто регистрировать российский домен и копировать на него сайт не есть хорошо
> Ну во-первых, в это нет ничего страшного если сайты будут на разных языках. Такие примеры есть.

Текущий магазин на украинском языке? Если да, то можно определять язык браузера пользователя по заголовкам и в зависимости от этого подсовывать посетителю ту или иную языковую версию сайта.

Answer (score 0):

Есть 2 варианта:

1. регистрировать отдельный домен, переносить и править контент сайта под другой регион - тексты, телефоны, адреса
2. Делать это же на Поддомене/разделе (двигается хуже/сложнее, чем отдельный сайт)

Дабы не зафильтровало за спам/дубликат контента/афилиат прописывается rel="alternate" hreflang=  под языковую версию/страну

https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/189077?hl=ru

А вот неплохое видео: http://seoprofy.ua/blog/na-doske/nomer-183